# eclipse: Java ME SDK plugin doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, plugins, java-me

I'm trying to work with Java ME Platform SDK in Eclipse Juno on Windows XP.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://goo.gl/26OMv): I installed Java ME SDK 3.2, MTJ toolkit and plugin for Eclipse. Everything was done without errors, and of course I have restarted Eclipse, but I can't see any effect:

Say, at this step from instruction: `Select Window > Open Perspective > Other and choose Java ME, then click OK.`

There is actually no "Java ME" perspective in "Other" list.

Or, this one: `Select Window > Preferences > Java ME and select Device Management, and click Manual Install.`

The same: I go to `Select Window > Preferences`, and there is NO "Java ME" item.

If I go to `Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation details`, then I see installed plugins there: Java ME SDK Demos, Java ME SDK Tools, Mobile Tools for Java Examples, Mobile Tools for Java SDK.

I have read instruction many times, and I still can't find what did I miss.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After enough reading I realized that there are some conflicts that occur with Mobile Tools for Java in the Juno edition. It works well with Indigo.

Alternatively, you could use Eclipse Pulsar for developing for the mobile platform. It comes preloaded with all the tools required for mobile app development.

Download Eclipse Pulsar (Helios SSR2) from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/pulsar-mobile-developers/heliossr2.